# Filter data based on multiple columns in second dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a Dataframe `df1` (original table) with multiple columns.

I have a filtered DataFrame `df2` with columns `date`, `agent_id`, `gps1`, `gps2` only 4 columns.

In `df1`, I have `date`, `agent_id` and `final_gps` along with other columns.

I want to filter all the data from `df1` which exists in `df2`, I want to compare based on.

**Df1.date == df2.date** & **df1.agent_id == df2.agent_id** & (**df1.final_gps == df2.gps1** or **df1.final_gps == df2.gps2**)

**df2 sample**

```
date       agent_id  gps1    gps2
14-02-2020  12abc   (1,2)   (7,6)
14-02-2020  12abc   (3,4)   (7,6)
14-02-2020  33bcd   (6,7)   (8,9)
20-02-2020  44hgf   (1,6)   (3,7)
20-02-2020  12abc   (3,5)   (3,1)
20-02-2020  33bcd   (3,4)   (3,6)
21-02-2020  12abc   (4,5)   (5,4)
```

**df1 sample**

```
date       agent_id final_gps   ….
10-02-2020  12abc   (1,2)       …
10-02-2020  33bcd   (8,9)       …
14-02-2020  12abc   (1,2)       …
14-02-2020  12abc   (7,6)       …
14-02-2020  12abc   (3,4)       …
14-02-2020  33bcd   (6,7)       …
14-02-2020  33bcd   (8,9)       …
14-02-2020  33bcd   (1,1)       …
14-02-2020  33bcd   (2,2)       …
18-02-2020  12abc   (1,2)       …
19-02-2020  44hgf   (6,7)       …
20-02-2020  12abc   (3,5)       …
20-02-2020  12abc   (3,1)       …
20-02-2020  44hgf   (1,6)       …
20-02-2020  44hgf   (3,7)       …
```

**required output:-**

```
date       agent_id final_gps   ….
14-02-2020  12abc   (1,2)       …
14-02-2020  12abc   (7,6)       …
14-02-2020  12abc   (3,4)       …
14-02-2020  33bcd   (6,7)       …
14-02-2020  33bcd   (8,9)       …
20-02-2020  12abc   (3,5)       …
20-02-2020  12abc   (3,1)       …
20-02-2020  44hgf   (1,6)       …
20-02-2020  44hgf   (3,7)       …
```

I tried this but it is giving me all the matching records which exists in `df2`, but I want strictly data only for those `agent_id` on that particular `date` and particular `gps` matching condition from `df1`.

```
df = df1[df1['date'].isin(df2['date']) & 
         df1['agent_id'].isin(df2['agent_id']) & 
        (df1['final_gps'].isin(df2['gps1']) | df1['final_gps'].isin(df2['gps2']))]
```

Comment: Is same output of both solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use multiple `isin` and chain them using `&` operator. Since `final_gps` can be either `gps1` or `gps2`, we use `|` operator in brackets:

```
out = (df1[df1['date'].isin(df2['date']) & 
           df1['agent_id'].isin(df2['agent_id']) & 
           (df1['final_gps'].isin(df2['gps1']) | df1['final_gps'].isin(df2['gps2']))]
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
         date agent_id final_gps ….
0  14-02-2020    12abc    (1, 2)  …
1  14-02-2020    12abc    (7, 6)  …
2  14-02-2020    12abc    (3, 4)  …
3  14-02-2020    33bcd    (6, 7)  …
4  14-02-2020    33bcd    (8, 9)  …
5  20-02-2020    12abc    (3, 5)  …
6  20-02-2020    12abc    (3, 1)  …
7  20-02-2020    44hgf    (1, 6)  …
8  20-02-2020    44hgf    (3, 7)  …
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for reshape `gps1` and `gps2` to `final_gps` first, so possible merge by all 3 columns (not necessary define `on`), remove duplicates by all columns and last sorting:

```
df = (df2.melt(id_vars=['date','agent_id'],
               value_vars=['gps1','gps2'],
               value_name='final_gps')
        .drop('variable', axis=1)
        .merge(df1)
        .drop_duplicates()
        .sort_values(by=['date','agent_id'], ignore_index=True))
print (df)
         date agent_id final_gps
0  14-02-2020    12abc     (1,2)
1  14-02-2020    12abc     (3,4)
2  14-02-2020    12abc     (7,6)
3  14-02-2020    33bcd     (6,7)
4  14-02-2020    33bcd     (8,9)
5  20-02-2020    12abc     (3,5)
6  20-02-2020    12abc     (3,1)
7  20-02-2020    44hgf     (1,6)
8  20-02-2020    44hgf     (3,7)
```

**Details**:

```
print (df2.melt(id_vars=['date','agent_id'],
               value_vars=['gps1','gps2'],
               value_name='final_gps'))

          date agent_id variable final_gps
0   14-02-2020    12abc     gps1     (1,2)
1   14-02-2020    12abc     gps1     (3,4)
2   14-02-2020    33bcd     gps1     (6,7)
3   20-02-2020    44hgf     gps1     (1,6)
4   20-02-2020    12abc     gps1     (3,5)
5   20-02-2020    33bcd     gps1     (3,4)
6   21-02-2020    12abc     gps1     (4,5)
7   14-02-2020    12abc     gps2     (7,6)
8   14-02-2020    12abc     gps2     (7,6)
9   14-02-2020    33bcd     gps2     (8,9)
10  20-02-2020    44hgf     gps2     (3,7)
11  20-02-2020    12abc     gps2     (3,1)
12  20-02-2020    33bcd     gps2     (3,6)
13  21-02-2020    12abc     gps2     (5,4)
```

Comment: Could you please confirm why you are not using column gps1 and gps2 in df2 while filtering data from df2

Comment: @pquest - because are melted to `final_gps`

Comment: @pquest - added ouput of `melt` to answer for see whats happens

Comment: Thanks..I will study about melt function..

Comment: the moment i saw “melt” i knew its jezreal